# How to send a Private Message by chat_id in Telegram by Bot in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, message, python-telegram-bot

I have to make a bot that will post a message and InlineKeyboardButton in a group and group members will respond on those InlineKeyboardButton. So on Callback query I'm showing them an alert message,

**And now I want to send a Private Message to each responder directly into their inbox, not in the group.**

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Sends a message with three inline buttons attached."""
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("opt_a", callback_data='A')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("opt_b", callback_data='B')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("opt_c", callback_data='C')],

    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard, resize_keyboard=False)
    update.message.reply_text("Question: Please Select an Option", reply_markup=reply_markup)


def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and show the alert."""
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer(text=f"Thanks for responding", show_alert=True)

    #############################################################
    Chat_id = query.message.chat.id
```

What I need to do is in the below line of code

```
# Send_Private_Message(chat_id=Chat_id, message_text = "Text of the message will b here...")
```

Now Here I want to send a Private Message to the user who responds
to inline Keyboard, I got his Chat ID here above in the variable "Chat_id",
But unable to find a way to send a Private Message to that person by his "Chat_id"

```
updater = Updater("TOKEN")

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

# Start the Bot
updater.start_polling()

# Bot in Idle Position
updater.idle()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Bot.send_message`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message) method. the bot instance is availbale as [`context.bot`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackcontext.html#telegram.ext.CallbackContext.bot). Note that [`(update.)message.reply_text`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_text) is just a *shortcut* for `send_message` ;)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`